# Why is my Elevator Murderous?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I made a piston elevator on Minecraft Xbox 360 edition. It is about 62 blocks high, it's a basic piston elevator but each level consists of a platform of redstone. I've tested it to make sure that the timing is right.

Whenever I use it, it kills me when I reach the top block. It seems to think I'm falling even though I'm going up. I removed the platform you land on at the top and replaced it with water but it still damages me a lot (it doesn't kill me though) and it can't squish me because there is nothing at the top to squish me with.

Is there a way to stop it from killing me?

Comment: Are you sure it's not squishing you at the top? Posting and idea of exactly what your elevator looks like would help. Either screenshots or diagrams :)

Comment: You've singlehandedly recreated the tower of terror.

Comment: @Emerica. - And on accident, too!

Comment: Can we see the design? if we can it will be easier to find your problem.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you've done that the elevator ends up killing you but this is in fact accurate physics : no matter which direction you go (down, up, even left or right), it's the sudden stop at the end that kills you. So remember : don't drink and drive !

Comment: Perhaps it shoves you up so high so fast that minecraft thinks that you are higher than you really are, causing you to die?

Comment: Ok it's a basic piston elevator not a zipper or anything like that but each level(piston thing that pushes out than up)consists of a platform of redstone.ive tested it to make sure that the timings right and it is but I removed the platform you land on at the top and replaced it with water but it still damages me a lot it doesn't kill me though and it can't squish me because there is nothing at the top to squish me with

Comment: You should probably port it over to a multiplayer world so that people can observe what happens as you go up or down

Comment: You could be accumulating a distance fallen value because you never truly contact ground while being piston launched. In that case, when you finally reach the top you will take all of the falling damage accumulated at once. I know this was an issue with the jetpack in tekkit a while back.

Comment: This is also why if you get into a minecraft and go off a mountain, then get out, you will die. Or when zombie pigment are in lAva for a long time, then die when they come out

Comment: @emarica,so basically I should just turn it into a ride and build a theme park around it?! :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be because the piston extension NOT BASE does not count as a full block, but it depends what type of elevator.

To see if you are on a full block or not press F3(PC), there is something saying g:true/false (if its true you are standing on a full block)